# Gradient coloring 3D vectors in Gnuplot

Tags: vector, gnuplot, gradient

Does anyone know how to apply gradient coloring for 3D vectors in Gnuplot?
I would like to do something like written here, but applying for vectors instead of points: http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_4.5/rgb_variable.html

Thank You in advance!

Comment: And where exactly do you have problems? Should be straightforward, the last `using` column contains the color information in both cases.

Comment: I don't understand how this work @Christoph . For example in in the first script on the above linked website the plot command invokes 3 columns, $1,$2 and $3, because it uses points (if I understand well): plot 'rgb_variable.dat' using (xrgb($1,$2,$3)):(yrgb($1,$2,$3)):(rgb($1,$2,$3))      with points pt 7 ps 4 lc rgb variable notitle. But I would like to use vectors, where the data file contains 6 columns: x,y,z,dx,dy,dz, respectivly.